# Pushing data to Google spreadsheet through JavaScript running in browser

Tags: javascript, jsonp, google-sheets, cors, google-sheets-api

I am working on an web application where I would like to allow the user to push data to her own Google spreadsheet.

Firstly I tried to use [Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/) but it doesn't seem to cover the Spreadsheet API (https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/).

Then I decided to use directly the [Google Spreadsheets API version 3.0](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/). I manage to retrieve the user's spreadsheets using `jQuery` and `JSONP`:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full?alt=json-in-script&access_token=' + access_token,
  dataType: 'JSONP',
  success: function(data){
    // use the spreadsheets
  }
});
```

In the same method I retrieve the sheets from the user selected spreadsheet. Then I have to `POST` the data to the selected sheet. And here comes the problem: can't do it using `JSONP`. And the Google server seems not to support `CORS`. I get the following error in the browser:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/... Origin ..mysite.. is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I was looking into this too about 8 months. I stumbled across [a blog post written by Martin Hawskey](http://mashe.hawksey.info/2011/10/google-spreadsheets-as-a-database-insert-with-apps-script-form-postget-submit-method/). I followed the guide here and I was able to set up a HTML form posting to a spreadsheet.

Effectively you set up a published web app inside the spreadsheet that can receive the data. To get around the CORS issues you target a hidden iframe on the page. I would replicate the code in this post but there is a fair bit of it.

**DEMO**

- [Here is the HTML form.](http://mashe.hawksey.info/examlpes/insert-eg.html)
- [Here is the spreadsheet receiving the data.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqGkLMU9sHmLdDlXcU52LWZHZUdfallfbE10T2tMLWc&hl=en_GB#gid=1)

I'll provide some advice that I wish I was given when I started looking at this. If you can... try and set up a PHP server you can use. Posting the data is a lot easier and flexible. I now use [Zend GData](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.gdata.spreadsheets.html) religiously at work and wish I had found it sooner :)

**EDIT**

Marting Hawskey has updated this to support a AJAX submission without the use of a hidden iframe. [See here](http://mashe.hawksey.info/2014/07/google-sheets-as-a-database-insert-with-apps-script-using-postget-methods-with-ajax-example/).

Comment: I based my solution based on your suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Updated the example referenced here to allow true ajax submission e.g without hidden iframe. See http://mashe.hawksey.info/2014/07/google-sheets-as-a-database-insert-with-apps-script-using-postget-methods-with-ajax-example/

Comment: I am still receiving the CORS error and I can't see anything relevant to getting around it in the new @mhawksey post you linked.

Answer (score 43):

### *Step-by-step* instructions with screenshots

After reading *Martin Hawskey*'s *good* introduction (*to sending data from an HTML form to a Google Spreadsheet*) and seeing a few gaps/assumptions, we decided to write a ***detailed/comprehensive tutorial with step-by-step instructions*** which a *few* people have found useful:

> [https://github.com/dwyl/**html**-form-**send**-email-via-**google-script**-without-server](https://github.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server)

The script saves any data sent via `HTTP POST` in the Google Spreadsheet, and *optionally* forwards the content to an email address. (*useful if you want to be notified of new data*)

#### HTML Form:

[image: contact form]

#### Result (*row in sheet*):

[image: row in sheet]

Hope it helps others.