# Update/Add data to Google Spreadsheet Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, google-sheets

I am trying to update/add data to a google spreadsheet which will act as a database. [Here](https://docs.google.com/a/sas.edu.sg/spreadsheets/d/1qPcO2SDbnyHcmxtbTb8DmG_f2_grEGIW1MaThSoFzFc/edit#gid=0) is my spreadsheet and my [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmm51xaL/1/). In the fiddle I can GET information; however, I am not sure how to POST new information yet. It doesn't see as easy as setting `data.feed.entry[4]['gsx$content']["$t"];` to the value I want. How would I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you have no `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'`

You need to make a jsonp request so just modify your url adding `&callback=?` and jQuery does the rest

```
var url = "http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1qPcO2SDbnyHcmxtbTb8DmG_f2_grEGIW1MaThSoFzFc/od6/public/values?alt=json&callback=?";
```

This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dejandomarcas/pmm51xaL/3/)

Regards!

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding; however, I am not exactly sure how this will help when trying to change the data on the google spreadsheet. I have tried making `data.feed.entry[4]['gsx$content']["$t"] = "new value"` but I don't believe that is correct. I hope that is clear now. Thanks

Comment: Hello, sorry about that. I think this link from another thread could be helpful for you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887737/pushing-data-to-google-spreadsheet-through-javascript-running-in-browser). Regards!

Comment: This couldn't be more helpful. Thanks a ton!