# Use Google Apps Script functions in project

Tags: javascript, database, web-applications, web, google-apps-script

I am very new to Google Apps Scripts and am curious how I can use functions created in my own project. For example, I have a script bound to a spreadsheet with just one function:

```
function addOrder(title, content) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow([ Date(), title, content]);
}
```

It simply takes 2 arguments and adds a row to the spreadsheet with that data. I have deployed it as a web app, but I'm not sure how to use this function in an environment like [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spreadsheet bound scripts run server side and the `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` method you are using will only work in the context of a spreadsheet bound script since it's the only case where the script actually "sees" an active spreadsheet. When you deploy this as a webapp you will have to tell the script which spreadsheet it must look at using for example the `SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheet ID')` method.

But even doing so will not allow for using such a code outside of Google environment (as in JS fiddle for example) since [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) is specific to Google Apps service.

You have to remember that Google Apps Script is *based* on JavaScript but is not "plain" JavaScript , it uses a lot of specific services that work only in relation with Google Apps.

---

**edit** to answer your comment below :

the code used in the spreadsheet to work as a data server goes like this : (this is deployed as a webapp without user interface. It runs as a service

```
function doGet(e) {
  if(e.parameter.mode==null){return ContentService.createTextOutput("error, wrong request").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT)};
  var mode = e.parameter.mode;
  var value = e.parameter.value;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1yad5sZZt-X6bIftpR--OSyf3VZWf3Jxx8UJBhh7Arwg');
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[0];
  if(mode=='read'){
    var sheetValues =  sh.getDataRange().getValues();// get data from sheet
    var valToReturn = ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(sheetValues)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    return valToReturn;// send it as JSon string
    }
  if(mode=='write'){
    var val = Utilities.base64Decode(value,Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);// decode base64 and get an array of numbers
    Logger.log(val);// see it !
    var stringVal = ''; // create an empty string
    for(var n in val){
      stringVal += String.fromCharCode(val[n]);// add each character in turn
    }
    var sheetValues =  JSON.parse(stringVal);// convert the string into an object (2D array)
    Logger.log(sheetValues);// check result
    sh.getRange(1,1,sheetValues.length,sheetValues[0].length).setValues(sheetValues);// update the sheet
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(sheetValues)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);// send back the result as a string
    }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('error').setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);// in case mode is not 'read' nor 'write'... should not happen ! 
}
```

you can call this service by its url + parameters and it will get / set values in the spreadsheet. This is a basic example but it works nicely.

below it the [webapp code](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzYzwX9lTGTvy0gVdUJlChLP5626d_loAnZNvaoisaxupGPAd4/exec) of the Ui that uses this service in [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yad5sZZt-X6bIftpR--OSyf3VZWf3Jxx8UJBhh7Arwg/edit#gid=0)

```
var stylePanel = {'padding':'50px', 'background':'#FFA'};
var styleButton = {'padding':'5px', 'border-radius':'5px', 'borderWidth':'1px', 'borderColor':'#DDD','fontSize':'12pt'};
var styleTextItalic = {'fontSize':'12pt','fontStyle':'italic','fontFamily':'arial,sans-serif','color':'#F00'};
var styleTextNormal = {'fontSize':'12pt','fontStyle':'normal','fontFamily':'arial,sans-serif','color':'#00F'};
var styleLabel = {'fontSize':'12pt','color':'#F00'};
var url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwPioVjYMSrmhKnJOaF2GG83dnstLWI7isU9SF1vxPV8td-g9E7/exec';
var numRow = 21;// the number of rows in the grid = number of rows in the SS + 1
;
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('url_fetch_demo');
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setStyleAttributes(stylePanel);
  var headers = ['Field Name','Your answer'];// grid title
  var grid = app.createGrid(numRow+2,2);// create the grid with right size
  var wait = app.createImage('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/211279/loading3T.gif').setId('wait').setVisible(false);// get a spinner image in animated gif
  var handlerWrite = app.createServerHandler('writeSheet').addCallbackElement(grid);// 2 handlers for the buttons
  var handlerRead = app.createServerHandler('readSheet').addCallbackElement(grid);
  var Chandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(wait).setVisible(true);// a client handler for the spinner
  var buttonWrite = app.createButton('Write to Sheet',handlerWrite).addClickHandler(Chandler).setStyleAttributes(styleButton);
  var buttonRead = app.createButton('Read from Sheet',handlerRead).addClickHandler(Chandler).setStyleAttributes(styleButton);
  for(var n=1 ; n < numRow ; n++){
    for(var m=0 ; m < 2 ; m++){ // create all the textBoxes with names & IDs
      var textBox = app.createTextBox().setText('no value').setName('text'+n+'-'+m).setId('text'+n+'-'+m).setStyleAttributes(styleTextNormal);
    //if(m==0){textBox.setEnabled(false)};// prevent writing to left column (optional)
      grid.setWidget(n,m,textBox);// place widgets
    }
  }
  grid.setWidget(numRow,0,buttonRead).setWidget(numRow,1,buttonWrite).setWidget(numRow+1,1,wait) // place buttons
  .setWidget(0,0,app.createLabel(headers[0]).setStyleAttributes(styleLabel)) // and headers
  .setWidget(0,1,app.createLabel(headers[1]).setStyleAttributes(styleLabel));
  app.add(panel.add(grid));
  return app; // show Ui
}

function writeSheet(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById('wait').setVisible(false);// spinner will be hidden when fct returns
  var dataArrayImage = [];// an array to get typed values
  for(var n=1 ; n < numRow ; n++){ 
    var row=[];
    for(var m=0 ; m < 2 ; m++){
      row.push(e.parameter['text'+n+'-'+m]); // get every value in every "cell"
      var textBox = app.getElementById('text'+n+'-'+m).setStyleAttributes(styleTextItalic);// update "cells" style
      //textBox.setText('written value = '+e.parameter['text'+n+'-'+m]);// rewrite to the cells - not usefull but serves to check while debugging
    }
    dataArrayImage.push(row);// store one row(=2cells)
  }
  var UiValues = JSON.stringify(dataArrayImage);// stringfy the array
  var newValues = url+'?mode=write&value='+Utilities.base64Encode(UiValues,Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);// add to url & parameters+ encode in pure ASCII characters
  Logger.log(newValues);// check in logger
  var check = UrlFetchApp.fetch(newValues).getContent();// get back the result
  Logger.log(check);// check result = newValues sent back in bytes format
  return app;//update Ui
}

function readSheet(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById('wait').setVisible(false);
  var returnedValue = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+'?mode=read').getContentText();// get data from server
  Logger.log(returnedValue);// check values
  var sheetValues = JSON.parse(returnedValue);
  for(var n=1 ; n < numRow ; n++){
    for(var m=0 ; m < 2 ; m++){
      var textBox = app.getElementById('text'+n+'-'+m).setStyleAttributes(styleTextNormal);
      textBox.setText(sheetValues[n-1][m]);// iterate and update cells values
    }
  }
return app;// update Ui
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all this helpful information. What would you suggest the best way of adding items to a google spreadsheet outside of the google environment is then? Thanks.

Comment: @breadedturtle You can use (1) the ContentService http://goo.gl/pIomAK like a backend server or (2) the Google Sheets API http://goo.gl/epfT3p for dding items to a google spreadsheet outside of the google environment.

Comment: @breadturtle - if you're interested, try these 2 urls : a [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yad5sZZt-X6bIftpR--OSyf3VZWf3Jxx8UJBhh7Arwg/edit?usp=sharing) and a [webapp](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzYzwX9lTGTvy0gVdUJlChLP5626d_loAnZNvaoisaxupGPAd4/exec)

Comment: @Sergeinsas is there any open source code of your webapp so I can see exactly what it is doing? Thanks.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanov I have successfully use the Google Sheets API to read data, but I'm still confused on how to write data with it. (see [other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303174/update-add-data-to-google-spreadsheet-database/26547787#26547787))