# php / laravel Display Excel in a web page as real sheet

Tags: html, excel, laravel

I asked if could be possible to display for example data from a mysql db in an excel sheet on a webpage as real excel sheet (such as excel online)
Thx a lot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pushing data to Google spreadsheet through JavaScript running in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887737/pushing-data-to-google-spreadsheet-through-javascript-running-in-browser)

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had a quick google, it seems you basically need to set up a google spreadsheet, publish it and then push your data with an app you set up in the sheet.

Have a look here: [Pushing data to Google spreadsheet through JavaScript running in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887737/pushing-data-to-google-spreadsheet-through-javascript-running-in-browser)